# Writing to and reading from a file at the same time

Tags: c++, ifstream, ofstream

I have two processes. One writes to a file, one has to read from it (At the same time..). So there's two `fstream`s open at a given time for the file (Although they may be in different processes).
I wrote a simple test function to crudely implement the sort of functionality I need:

```
void test_file_access()
{
    try {
        std::string file_name = "/Users/xxxx/temp_test_folder/test_file.dat"; 

        std::ofstream out(file_name,
                          std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app | std::ios_base::binary);
        out.write("Hello\n", 7);

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

        std::array<char, 4096> read_buf;
        std::ifstream in(file_name,
                         std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);

        if (in.fail()) {
            std::cout << "Error reading file" << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        in.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);

        //Exception at the below line.
        in.read(read_buf.data(), read_buf.size());
        auto last_read_size = in.gcount();
        auto offset = in.tellg();

        std::cout << "Read [" << read_buf.data() << "] from file. read_size = " << last_read_size
                  << ", offset = " << offset << std::endl;

        out.write("World\n", 7);

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

        //Do this so I can continue from the position I was before?
        //in.clear();

        in.read(read_buf.data(), read_buf.size());
        last_read_size = in.gcount();
        offset = in.tellg();

        std::cout << "Read [" << read_buf.data() << "] from file. read_size = " << last_read_size
                  << ", offset = " << offset << std::endl;

        //Remove if you don't have boost.
        boost::filesystem::remove(file_name);
    }
    catch(std::ios_base::failure const & ex)
    {
        std::cout << "Error : " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "System error : " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    }
}


int main()
{
    test_file_access();
}
```

---

Run, and the output is like this:

```
Error : ios_base::clear: unspecified iostream_category error
System error : Operation timed out
```

---

So two questions,

1. What is going wrong here? Why do I get an `Operation timed out` error?
2. Is this an incorrect attempt to do what I need to get done? If so, what are the problems here?

Comment: Construction two fstream objects like this to handle read and writes simultaneously tends to mess with the end of file flag. To do it this way, you'd have to use `seekg()` before a read and `seekp()` before a write.

Comment: @Jon: Does that mean that for the `ifstream`, I have to `open, read, remember the position, close -- open, seek to position, read, remember the position, close`? And for the `ofstream`,  `open, append, close`?

Comment: No, you don't have to close the file. For instance, `seekg()` allows you to do something such as `inputStream.seekg(0, inputStream.end);` which means if you call that before a `read()`, it takes into account the end-of-file location from the previous `write()`

Comment: @Jon: Tried your suggestion, still the same error. Do note that in the first place, I open the `in` stream only after the first write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write into this file 7 bytes, but then try to read 4096 bytes. So in stream will read only 7 bytes and throw an exception as requested. Note that if you catch this exception the rest of the code will be executed correctly, e.g. `last_read_size` will be 7 and you can access those 7 bytes in buffer.

Comment: No, if I comment out the `in.exceptions(...` line, this is what is printed in the subsequent `cout`: `Read [ V�] from file. read_size = 0, offset = -1`

Comment: Alright, you need to flush `out` buffer to ensure that changes are visible. I just wanted to point that exception is thrown correctly.

Comment: Ok, but `out.flush()` immediately after the write also has no effect. same result.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. After adding `flush` after every write and setting read bytes count to 7 instead of 4096 this code works fine.

Comment: Ok, I made the mistake of having a `seekg` in there. After removing it, the first read is fine. I'll check the rest.

Comment: Ok, the first read is fine, but even with flushing after second write, the second read reads 0 bytes.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not trying to read `read_buf.size()` bytes first time? because doing so will set fail bit so second read will fail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144526/discussion-between-nakiya-and-vtt).